# If exists update column else create, but with tricky parts (I think)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.2

Here's the deal:
I'm creating a rails RESTful API for storing information in a PostgreSQL database, and I'm using Parents and Childs controllers and Parent and Child models (example names).

What I'll need is to check whether a Child record already exists, but not by id. I need to check if Child as already a record with the same "type" and "parent_id".

If a record is found, I will need to update the column "values", but adding the new "value", not replacing, as in:

```
Child data 1: {type => type1, values => { info1 => info1, val1 => 1 }, parent_id => parent1}
Child data 2: {type => type1, values => { info2 => info2, val2 => 2 }, parent_id => parent1}

Final result: {type => type1, values => *[*{ info1 => info1, val1 => 1}, {info2 => info2, val2 => 2 }*]*, parent_id => parent1}
```

I've seen a few topics and I currently have this in the Child Model:

```
before_create :check_child_exists

private

def check_child_exists
    @child = Child.find_by_type_and_parent_id(self.type, self.parent_id)
    if @child != nil
        @child.update_attribute(:value, <*>) # <*> = hash + newhash (an array of hashes)
    end
end
```

Can anyone help me with this? I would be much appreciated.
If any additional information is required, please let me know.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def update_previous_child
  conditions = {type: self.type, parent_id: self.parent_id}

  if existing_child = Child.find_by(conditions) # or Child.where(conditions).last
    new_value = (existing_child.value || []) + [new_hash]
    existing_child.update_attribute(:value, new_value)
  end
end
```

That should do what you want. But each time you're creating a child, only the last one will be updated. If you want all the existing rows to be updated, do this:

```
def update_previous_children
  conditions = {type: self.type, parent_id: self.parent_id}

  Child.where(conditions).each do |existing_child|
    new_value = (existing_child.value || []) + [new_hash]
    existing_child.update_attribute(:value, new_value)
  end
end
```

If you know how to properly serialize your new hash, you could write some SQL to use `update_all` on the `ActiveRecord::Relation` returned by `where`, rather than turning it into an array and using `update_attribute` on each entry.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'll give it a go when I can (I'm still working in the testing part of the api). One small question: I didn't understand the part where you said that "only the last one will be updated" when I'm creating a child, can you clarify?

Comment: There might be multiple children that fulfill your conditions criteria. If you use the first method, only the last (the one with the highest ID in this case) will be updated.

Comment: Oh right, that won't be the case since all the child records of the same type and parent_id should be in one database record. The case of multiple lines isn't a problem, since the parent_id and type can be considered a primary key. Thanks for your help. (I would upvote your comment, but I can't cause I don't have enough reputation, sorry :( )